# Como juntar dois arquivos csv no R?

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-html, csv, r

meu problema é o seguinte: Tenho dois arquivos de dados no formato csv com mesmo número de colunas e mesmos nomes de colunas (veja abaixo). Peço para ler os arquivos da seguinte forma:

```
> dados_1 <- read.csv("Teste_01.csv")
> dados_2 <- read.csv("Teste_02.csv")
```

a leitura é feita corretamente (sem erros), mostrando o resultado

```
> dados_1

A Ins Run Time.s Acc
S In1 1   141.60 0.902
S In1 2   150.20 0.905
S In2 1   180.10 0.887
S In2 2   161.50 0.898
P In1 1    75.37 0.840
P In1 2    92.28 0.879
P In2 1   170.90 0.833
P In2 2   114.00 0.833

> dados_2

A Ins Run Time.s Acc
S In1 1   171.50 0.899
S In1 2   166.90 0.887
S In2 1   154.30 0.889
S In2 2   167.10 0.844
S In3 1   162.50 0.915
S In3 2   156.00 0.880
P In1 1   121.50 0.859
P In1 2   122.20 0.874
P In2 1   159.10 0.856
P In2 2    73.70 0.872
P In3 1    10.95 0.857
P In3 2   119.00 0.848
```

Agora preciso unir os dados destas duas tabelas da seguinte forma: todos os dados da primeira tabela devem ser mantidos, e ao juntar as duas tabelas os dados da primeira tabela devem substituir os dados da segunda tabela que estão com o mesmo nome nas colunas "A" e "Ins", ou seja, preciso obter o seguinte resultado

```
A Ins Run Time.s Acc
S In1 1   141.60 0.902     (veio de dados_1)
S In1 2   150.20 0.905     (veio de dados_1)
S In2 1   180.10 0.887     (veio de dados_1)
S In2 2   161.50 0.898     (veio de dados_1)
S In3 1   162.50 0.915     (veio de dados_2)
S In3 2   156.00 0.880     (veio de dados_2)
P In1 1    75.37 0.840     (veio de dados_1)
P In1 2    92.28 0.879     (veio de dados_1)
P In2 1   170.90 0.833     (veio de dados_1)
P In2 2   114.00 0.833     (veio de dados_1)
P In3 1    10.95 0.857     (veio de dados_2)
P In3 2   119.00 0.848     (veio de dados_2)
```

Alguém sabe me informar como posso fazer isso? Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o código abaixo resolve o teu problema:

```
aux         <- dados_2[!(dados_2$Ins %in% unique(dados_1$Ins)) | 
!(dados_2$A %in% unique(dados_1$A)), ]
dados_final <- rbind(dados_1, aux)
```

O data frame `dados_final` criado assim não fica na mesma ordem da tua pergunta, os resultados são idênticos.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia resolver este problema usando a função `which` para encontrar as posições dos IDs (A e Ins) da tabela dados_2 que não se repetem em dados_1.

```
posicao <- 
  which(!(dados_2$Ins %in% dados_1$Ins) |
          !(dados_2$A %in% dados_1$A))

# concatena linhas
dados_3 <- rbind(dados_1, dados_2[posicao, ])

dados_3
```